# How I Fill listbox from 2 different sources (folders/directories)?

Tags: vb.net, listbox, datasource, getfiles, getdirectories

I'm trying to sort some documents into a listbox, If my document is a collection scanned pictures into folders, it must list at lisbox1 each folder, if my document is a .pdf it must be added too

```
directo = "D:\books\

ListBox1.DataSource = IO.Directory.GetDirectories(directo, "*.*", IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
ListBox1.DataSource = IO.Directory.GetFiles(directo, "*.pdf", IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
```

I  get as result:

D:\books\Book-A

D:\books\Book-B

D:\books\Book-C

or

D:\books\Book-E.pdf

D:\books\Book-F.pdf

D:\books\Book-G.pdf

but i can't get it mixed, eachtime the listbox show me just one source or another. Any suggestion to list?

Comment: Use a TreeView instead of a ListBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the return values of `GetDirectories` and `GetFiles` to a `List(Of String)`, and then merge the two together. This merged list can then be assigned to the DataSource property of the ListBox. See below for an example.

```
Dim directories As List(Of String) = Directory.GetDirectories(directo, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList()
Dim files As List(Of String) = Directory.GetFiles(directo, "*.pdf", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList()

Dim dataSourceList As New List(Of String)
dataSourceList.AddRange(directories)
dataSourceList.AddRange(files)

ListBox1.DataSource = dataSourceList
```

Comment: You don't need to call `.ToList` and create `List(Of String)` in the first two lines. Unnecessary load. Just get the string arrays and add them to the `dataSourceList`.